# System.Timers.Timer.SynchronizingObject ManagedThreadId not from Main Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, entity-framework, timer

I'm working on a WPF app (MVVM) with Entity Framework. I want to query a table on the SQL server on a given interval to display the updated DB values to the user. For this purpose I set up a timer in my ViewModel like so:

```
RefreshTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000.0);
RefreshTimer.Enabled = true;
RefreshTimer.SynchronizingObject = new Synchronizer();
RefreshTimer.Elapsed += RefreshTimer_Elapsed;
```

where the Synchronizer is an implementation of ISynchronizeInvoke:

```
internal class Synchronizer : ISynchronizeInvoke
{
    private object _sync = new object();

    public bool InvokeRequired { get { return true; } }

    public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
    {
        var result = new SimpleAsyncResult();

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
            result.AsyncWaitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            try
            {
                result.AsyncState = Invoke(method, args);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                result.Exception = exception;
            }
            result.IsCompleted = true;
        });

        return result;
    }

    public object EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (!result.IsCompleted)
        {
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }

        return result.AsyncState;
    }

    public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            return method.DynamicInvoke(args);
        }
    }
}

internal class SimpleAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
{
    object _state;

    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle { get; internal set; }

    public object AsyncState
    {
        get
        {
            if (Exception != null)
            {
                throw Exception;
            }
            return _state;
        }
        internal set
        {
            _state = value;
        }
    }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously { get { return IsCompleted; } }

    internal Exception Exception { get; set; }
}
```

If I understand correctly, the SynchronizingObject should marshal the Elapsed event on the thread the SynchronizingObject was created on. In my case that is the main thread. Now consider the following code to handle the event:

```
private void RefreshTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"RefreshTimer ManagedThreadID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    RefreshTimer.SynchronizingObject.Invoke((Action)(() => { TestMethod(); }), null);
}

public void TestMethod()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TestMethod ManagedThreadID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}
```

The TestMethod is where I would update/reload my Entity object so the View would automatically display the latest data. When I try to do that I get a InvalidOperationException stating *The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it*

The output is:

```
RefreshTimer ManagedThreadID: 5
TestMethod ManagedThreadID: 5
RefreshTimer ManagedThreadID: 4
TestMethod ManagedThreadID: 4
RefreshTimer ManagedThreadID: 8
TestMethod ManagedThreadID: 8
```

And I suspect this is the reason I get the above exception. I expect the output to be:

```
RefreshTimer ManagedThreadID: 5
TestMethod ManagedThreadID: 1
RefreshTimer ManagedThreadID: 4
TestMethod ManagedThreadID: 1
RefreshTimer ManagedThreadID: 8
TestMethod ManagedThreadID: 1
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can get the SynchronizingObject.Invoke method to execute on the main thread?

Comment: You shouldn't use a worker thread timer with GUI code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the dispatcher to schedule the delegate to be executed on the dispatcher thread:

```
private void RefreshTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"RefreshTimer ManagedThreadID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { TestMethod(); }))
}
```

You may also want to read this: https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2017/02/15/how-to-test-code-that-uses-singletons-like-application-current-dispatcher/